# Jquery ajax not execute success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

Am sending requesty by ajax to insert data in database. After success submiting my button message was not changed. On press i fire message `Please wait...` when success is fired set new html value `Done`. Records in db is success created but button text to `Done` was not changed.

My script:

```
var Friend = {

    // Add new friend
    add: function() {
        var btn = $(".btn-add-friend");

        btn.click(function() {

            $(this).html("Please wait...");

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: baseurl + "/FriendRequest/send",
                data: {
                    friend: $(this).data('friend')
                },

                success: function(xhr, status) {
                    $(this).html("Done"); // Not wortk

                    alert("done"); // <-- Work 
                },
                error: function(response, s, e) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                complete: function () {
                     //. the some from success
                }
            });
        });
      },

    // Initialise
    init: function() {
        Friend.add();
    }
};
```

Html:

```
<button type="button" id="item-<?=$person->account_id;?>" class="btn  btn-xs btn-add-friend has-spinner" data-friend="<?= $person->account_id;?>"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Friend</button>
```

When i click on button text was changet to `Please wait..` but after success not changed to `Done` and alert is successful executed.

looks like it is not part of DOM after click! ALso i try with `on()` the some result i get.

Comment: Check your variable `baseurl` is having some value before passing it in `url`.

Comment: baseurl is not problem its just url for controller, after click all data succesful inserted in database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` inside the ajax function callbacks is .... the ajax call, not the clicked element.
You have to replace it with it

```
add: function() {
    var btn = $(".btn-add-friend");

    btn.click(function() {

        var self = $(this);

        self.html("Please wait...");

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: baseurl + "/FriendRequest/send",
            data: {
                friend: self.data('friend')
            },
            success: function(xhr, status) {
                self.html("Done");
            },
```

Comment: Am looping friend list form db and there is 100 users with the some button. If i set `btn.html("done")` i was change all buttons to done :( for that i need to point only on one button

Comment: The you'll need a variable to hold the `this` value, edited

Comment: Right.... Thank now work. So next time i need to define variable witch will hold `this` thanks man.

Comment: Every function generally has it's own `this` value, so when `this` inside the click function is the clicked element, it's the same with the ajax function, `this` inside the `success` function is the ajax call, not the element.

Comment: Yup i understand now, u save me alot time. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

To use `this`, you need additional attribute. Add the following with `url`

```
context:this
```

So, the updated code will be

```
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: baseurl + "/FriendRequest/send",
            context:this,
            data: {
                friend: $(this).data('friend')
            },

            success: function(xhr, status) {
                $(this).html("Done"); // Will work

                alert("done"); // <-- Work 
            },
            error: function(response, s, e) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            complete: function () {
                 //. the some from success
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the callback, this refers to the `jqXHR` object of the Ajax call, not the element. so try to assign it to a variable before ajax request, then use this variale inside success function:

```
//Before ajax request
var _this = $(this);

//Inside success function
_this.html("Done");
```

Hope this helps.